# System.IndexOutOfRangeException and SqlQuery method with Interface or Base Class

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a non-mapped property and get this error below.  I tried a base class and interface, but it keeps trying to map the SQL results to the class being sent in.  I don't want to copy this class to another, because there are a huge number of properties on this class and its a list of them.  The interface does not have the "Date" property.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Date'

**Method**

```
public List<T> GetTest<T>(int testId) where T : IBaseTestComplex
{
    return DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>("EXEC [Test].[GetTest] @TestId",
        new SqlParameter("TestId", testId)).ToList();
}
```

**Caller**

```
var tests = testRepository.GetTest<TestComplex>(testId);
```

Comment: The interface does not have the date property but does a implementation of the interface have it? Curious because this error in my head maps to ado.net exception of trying to get a column that does not exist in the result from the db... i.e reader["Date"]

Comment: The interface does NOT, but the class TestComplex does.

Comment: Can you share how you are currently keeping that property from being mapped?

Comment: I’m not doing anything particular. I thought it would only map properties belonging to the interface or base class but that isn’t the case with the SqlQuery function.

Comment: Yeah no the sqlquery function will try do a property to column matching, I can't really find anyway to ignore this either. Also it will get the properties from the generic type you pass in which in this case is TestComplex, you could generically type it as the base class instead if that has all the properties for the columns that come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a SqlDateReader to skip those exceptions being thrown hundreds of thousands times a day.

```
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DataContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("[Test].[GetTest]", connection))
                {
                    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
                    {
                        new SqlParameter("TestId", GetDataValue(testId))
                    };

                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());

                    connection.Open();

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                               games.Add(Get(dr));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```